# IOCP and non-blocking IO

Tags: select, iocp

I have 3rd party library that uses *non-blocking send, recv* (in Windows), so I can use *libevent* (or *libev*) with **select** backend to event loop. Is there easy way to use **IOCP** backend (*libevent2*, *libuv*)? Because in different manuals write, that i must use *WSASend, WSARecv* functions with some additional arguments (pointer to OVERLAPPED structure). How can I use **IOCP** backend event loop with this 3rd party library without rewriting its code? Or it is not impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

At the very least:

- you need to associate the socket that's used with the IOCP that you want to process the completions
- you need to create the socket with different flags.

Either of these likely requires that you change the library code.